# Smarter way of sending push notificaiton's to devices

Tags: android, ios, email, push-notification

I've spend the past month developing my application for android and ios.
I thought I was in the final stretch until i got to the subject of push notifications.......Now I've spent over a week trying to configure them for both android and ios with my django backend. I've been successful with android and gcm but ios has been a lot harder and i've been unsuccessful.

I know this question is not entirely code based. But it is a large problem for unexperienced developers i'm sure. Ok so thinking of solutions I've thought of emailing users notifications and telling them to keep their email push notifications on.

A problem with that is that users receive so much spam email and will be unwilling to do this. A solution would be to add VIP privileges to email as in the user only receives email notifications from specific email addresses like the one my site would use. Is there any way to achieve this in code like giving the user an alert "This application would like to access email vip privileges" then add vip privileges. Otherwise I'm going to provide links to documentation for users on how to allow vip privileges for users email applications.

Other thoughts were accessing facebook's notification api if they even have one or its even possible....

Answer (score 0):

Now both android and IOS support Firebase Notification servie. Please Use this notification that helps you.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/